# Hola, estoy haciendo un mini proyecto con un API de rick and morty, y tengo un problema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo este Map de la estancia donde estoy almacenando la información que me llega de la API, esta información primeramente la guarde en una colección en FareBase y me la pase a un estado de Redux en mi proyecto.

Ahora Resulta que pongo en consola ese estado para ver que la información me llegue correctamente, y lo hace.

El problema esta que este no se renderiza en mi proyecto. De ninguna manera.

No tengo idea de porque me ver en consola y ver la información por segmentos, pero no me renderiza la información en mi HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen dia, te recomiendo iniciar por hacer el [tour] , luego evaluamos tu publicacion, pero de salida tenemos problemas, estas compartiendo codigo en formto de imagen, lo cual es imposible de utilizar, cuando dices que no renderiza ... esperamos ver algun codigo de error o error o algo mas en los logs que ayude o proveea mas informacion sobre lo que se esta ejecutando ...

Comment: Bienvenido Miguel a SOes, antes que te den negativos, revisa estas recomendaciones: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR? Coloca todo el código mínimo necesario para que cualquier usuario pueda copiar/pegar y reproducir tu escenario. Edita el título de la pregunta con algo que sea más específico, de ese modo también incrementas la visibilidad de tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Hola debes de agregar el código de tu proyecto o mejor súbelo a GitHub y comparte el repo.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_) en la pregunta. Evita los enlaces externos. Y por supuesto, el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.